# QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: (only on mobile)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mobile-safari

So I have a responsive web-application built on Rails 4, and Ruby 2.0.0 and it works GREAT in all browsers on my desktop, and macbook pro, however on my iPhone 6 iOS 8.4.1 everytime that I click the search function the loading animation appears but no results! It just keeps loading and loading. Note: THIS DOES NOT HAVE TO DO WITH PRIVATE BROWSING!! It only happens on mobile devices using Safari even when I'm in normal browsing mode.

To investigate the issue further, I plugged in my iPhone via usb to my mac, opened up my Safari and clicked the Develop tab, and then clicked my iPhone. This essentially allowed me to access the Web Inspector tool to look into what errors the app was throwing.

When I hit refresh the below error was shown:

```
QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.
```

Then below it:

```
(anonymous function)
```

It's important to note that we are trying to use sessionStorage to store, temporarily, some additional values of a variable

Any help here would be great!

Comment: Can we see some client code ? Rails is back-end.

Comment: Sure, here's the relevant code that's the causing the issue - sessionStorage.setItem('searchCity', 'Toronto')
...
sessionStorage.getItem("searchCity")